# Why would git pull stall at the same point while "compressing objects", leading to "corrupt loose object"?

Tags: git, github, repository

If I `git pull` after a few hours I typically get a stalled pull process that can take up to 10 minutes.  After this it usually runs pretty quickly (2-3 seconds), until I let a larger gap go by.  I notice that it's always around the same objects (3650-3680 in my case) and it sort of clogs along, 3651... 3652... etc.  Instead of ripping through them like it should.  Once it gets to 3680ish it starts ripping through them again and completes a few seconds later.

What do you recommend?  Here's a printout of my latest pull:

```
Counting objects: 6512, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects:  56% (3677/6463)
```

There's just two of us on the repository and there's not a whole lot of code changes that would warrant such a demanding pull request.

When it finally does finish it says:

```
error: corrupt loose object '895fdc42e0015abc74e4cc958393027262374b90'
fatal: loose object 895fdc42e0015abc74e4cc958393027262374b90 (stored in /path/to/mysite/.git/objects/89/5fdc42e0015abc74e4cc958393027262374b90) is corrupt
error: failed to run repack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git fsck` on your central repo, and see what it says. It will probably report the same object as corrupt. Find out if it’s actually referred. If not, delete it. If it is referred, find out where it came from / who might have a copy of it and replace the corrupt object with a correct copy.

Comment: This file is not on the master or the other developer on the repository.  Does this mean it is not referred and may be deleted?

Comment: you can just move it out of the git dir (remember its location!) and see what happens. My answer was a little unspecific – to check if the object is in other repos, you should not look at the filesystem, but run `git show -p **SHA**`. The object might be in a packfile.